# Unable to build CSS from Drupal Aurora theme

Tags: ruby, drupal-7, rubygems

compass watch

> > > Change detected at 02:13:25 to: style.scss
> > >           error sass/style.scss (Line 20 of sass/partials/global/_base.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: aurora/susy-grid.
> > >       Load paths:
> > >         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/txmo/sites/all/themes/txmo_aurora/sass
> > >         /Users/davidfells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
> > >         /Users/davidfells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
> > >         Compass::SpriteImporter)

Running Ruby 1.9.3, latest versions of all gems freshly installed with JewelryBox

Comment: That's not an error installing the gem, it's an error installing documentation. Also, have you tried this with rvm instead of the system ruby?

Comment: I only just got RVM to install (using Jewelry Box, not RVM directly). As far as I can gather it's not successfully modifying my current Ruby, running ruby -v always shows the original version. This is to solve the base problem of " error sass/style.scss (Line 20 of sass/partials/global/_base.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: aurora/susy-grid." using Aurora with Drupal.

Comment: Rvm does not modify your original ruby, it installs another version in your home directory. Type `which ruby` to find out if you are running the .rvm version or not. If not, open a new shell window and do the same. Make sure the rvm ruby is in your path.

Comment: Ok, that was the answer. Things seem to have installed correctly but I'm still getting the same failure in the Drupal Aurora level running compass watch. I'm going to just rewrite this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, the problem was that I had the "aurora" gem installed. Uninstalling "aurora" allows "compass-aurora" to work as expected.